# SQLAlcemy relationships that work with MySQL generate error when used with Sql Server

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have some SQLAlchemy ORM code working with MySQL but when I change the underlying database to Sql Server I get the message Module 'user_group' has no mapped classes registered under the name 'foreign_keys'

Here's are the ORM definition of one of the primary classes:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __table_args__ = (
        {'schema':'admn'}
    )

    user_id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_name = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    _password = Column('password', Unicode(80), nullable=True)
    authentication_backend = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=False, default='application_db')

    groups = relationship(
        "Group",
        secondary="user_group",
        back_populates="users",
        cascade="all", passive_deletes = True)
```

Here's the definition of the other primary class:

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group'
    __table_args__ = (
        {'schema': 'admn'}
    )

    group_id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True, nullable=True)

    users = relationship(
        "User",
        secondary="user_group",
        back_populates="groups",
        cascade="all",
        passive_deletes=True)
```

And the secondary class that relates them:

```
class UserGroup(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_group'
    __table_args__ = (
        {'schema': 'admn'}
    )

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.user_id', ondelete="cascade", onupdate="cascade"), primary_key = True)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('group.group_id', ondelete="cascade", onupdate="cascade"), primary_key = True)
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error message in SQL Server but not MySql??

Michael

Relevant Traceback:

```
    user = Session.query(User).filter(User.user_name==user_name).first()
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 153, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1393, in query
    return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._set_entities(entities)
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 151, in _set_entities
    self._set_entity_selectables(self._entities)
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 181, in _set_entity_selectables
    ent.setup_entity(*d[entity])
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3619, in setup_entity
    self._with_polymorphic = ext_info.with_polymorphic_mappers
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 767, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1994, in _with_polymorphic_mappers
    configure_mappers()
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3013, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1811, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 184, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1656, in do_init
    self._setup_join_conditions()
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1731, in _setup_join_conditions
    can_be_synced_fn=self._columns_are_mapped
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1998, in __init__
    self._determine_joins()
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2065, in _determine_joins
    consider_as_foreign_keys=consider_as_foreign_keys
  File "<string>", line 2, in join_condition
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 964, in _join_condition
    a, a_subset, b, consider_as_foreign_keys)
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 996, in _joincond_scan_left_right
    b.foreign_keys,
  File "/home/michaell/projects/ddp_ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/clsregistry.py", line 198, in __getattr__
    self.__parent.name, key))
AttributeError: Module 'user_group' has no mapped classes registered under the name 'foreign_keys'
```

Comment: Post the error and its traceback, not just the message.

Comment: I'd try to use `Group.__table__.group_id` (same with `User`) in `ForeignKey` declarations instead of string names. I suspect that the problem might be in the default case of the names: lower in MySQL and upper in MS SQL.

Comment: Hmm. That exact syntax caused attribute errors  but I tried "Group.__table__.columns.group_id"   and that did not cause attribute errors, but I still ended up with the same  "..no mapped classes" error from SQL Alchemy.  I wonder if there's something I could look at (beyond the traceback) that might give more clues as to what it's stumbling on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to mentioning the SQL Server schema names as part of the table args, as in:

```
class UserGroup(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_group'
    __table_args__ = (
        {'schema': 'admn'}
)
```

The schema is named "admn".

You also have to mention the schema name in various strings in the ORM in which you are naming tables. Two examples I've found so far:

Foreign keys:

```
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('admn.user.user_id', ondelete="cascade", onupdate="cascade"), primary_key = True)
```

In relationships when you mention a table, such as a secondary table:

```
  users = relationship(
        "User",
        secondary="admn.user_group",
        back_populates="groups",
        cascade="all",
        passive_deletes=True)
```

It was this last place that was causing my mapper errors. IE as soon as I mentioned the schema name in secondary=... the mapper errors went away.